# gsub replace one quote with nothing

Tags: awk, gsub

**Input**:

```
aaaa, bbbb, ccc, "dddd, ddd1", eee
eee, "fff, ggg, hhh
```

**Output**:

```
aaaa, bbbb, ccc, "dddd, ddd1", eee
eee, fff, ggg, hhh
```

I think `gsub` should do it, but how to tell to replace " with nothing only then, if " is only once in all row (sometimes happens somehow by mistake).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do:

```
awk -F'"' 'NF==2{sub(/"/,"")}7' file
```

Comment: What if there are 3 quotes ?

Comment: @Jidder OP was asking **only once** case. The one-liner above is the solution to OP's problem.  If it has 3 quotes, the solution won't work for it.

Comment: @Jidder I don't get you sorry. why my command will remove `"` if there are three in a line? If there were 3 `"`, `NF==2` would be `false`, or I am wrong?

Comment: oh yeah, sorry my bad , i was talking about removing just single quotes first, then i came back to the comment with the wrong idea

Comment: Could also use `awk -F'"' 'NF<3{$1=$1}1'`

Comment: @Jidder that won't remove the `"`, instead, it replaces the quote by a whitespace. not OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below awk command,

```
$ awk '/^[^"]*"[^"]*$/{sub(/"/,"")}1' file
aaaa, bbbb, ccc, "dddd, ddd1", eee
eee, fff, ggg, hhh
```

The search pattern `^[^"]*"[^"]*$` matches the lines which has exactly one `"` quotes. Removing the double quotes on that line will give you the desired result. `sub` function would be enough for removing a single character from a line.

Comment: if there were 3 " " " then also should be removed one ". If five, than also remove 1 quote.

Comment: removing the one `"` from where(from which position)?